# Help! Nearly there on Android sync

Tags: android, synchronization

I've just got started with Android programming and have nearly got the SampleSync program running. There is one error I just can't get past - in the 'AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter' module, right at the end of when it runs.

In the snippet below, it's when the code tries to 'release' the 'provider'. It tries to do that line and always throws a NullPointerException.

Any thoughts on things I could try - I'm so close! :)

John

```
SyncResult syncResult = new SyncResult();
ContentProviderClient provider = null;
try {
    provider = mContext.getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(mAuthority);
    if (provider != null) {
        AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.this.onPerformSync(mAccount, mExtras, mAuthority, provider, syncResult);
    } else {
        syncResult.databaseError = true;
    }
} finally {
    if (provider != null) {
        provider.release();
    }
    if (!isCanceled()) {
        mSyncContext.onFinished(syncResult);
    }
    // synchronize so that the assignment will be seen by other threads
    // that also synchronize accesses to mSyncThread
    synchronized (mSyncThreadLock) {
        mSyncThread = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense for that line to throw a NullPointerException because it won't be executed if provider is null. The exception must be on a different line.

There's a good tutorial on sync adapters on the [c99 blog](http://www.c99.org/2010/01/23/writing-an-android-sync-provider-part-1/) that is described a lot better than the Google SampleSync example. I recommend you give that a read.